# Should I discard a feature whose max - min is smaller than 1e-5?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection, normalization

I'm training a neural network for regression. The input vector consists of $140$ entries.

For each feature vector entry, I calculate both `min` and `max` over the training set. The difference `max-min` of some entries are smaller than `1e-5`. I understand I can normalize such feature entries by say `MinMaxScalar`. However, if the difference `max-min` is this small, can I discard such entries since they seem to be so insensitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really know if they are 'insensitive' based on the magnitude of the values alone; it's the *variation* in the data that is relevant. It's entirely possible to have meaningful variation even when the magnitude is low. Since very small values sometimes lead to algorithmic problems, such features are frequently rescaled before use.

Of course, if you have practical reasons to expect that such a small range of values is not meaningful in your data, it would be reasonable to drop these features.

Comment: @Hi, could you elaborate a little on what makes a variation meaningful? And how to detect it?

Comment: @meTchaikovsky That rather depends on your dataset and question. But the *covariance* between the feature in question (with low variation) and the variable you are trying to predict is frequently informative. For e.g., if lower values for the predictor corresspond to lower values in your variable of interest, the variable is probably informative even if the range is 1e-5 or lower.